# No applications found in non-root user account

Tags: kde, opensuse, desktop-environment, application, plasma5

I'm currently running OpenSuse Tumbleweed and after I uninstalling snapd package I reboot my PC and I found my plasma desktop without any applications available. I can see some files that I got in my desktop, but I can't run any application. Even if a try to open a folder a dialog comes out asking me which application I want to open the file with. Of course there is none available.
Although this only happen in the non-root user account, because I can still press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then I log in the TTY1 session as root and I run startx and the root graphical session works perfectly.

I tried deleting the files "plasmarc", "plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc" and "plasmashellrc" found in ~/.config but none of them solved anything.

Please let me know which commands should I paste because to be honest I'm really newbie in the linux environment and whenever I had a problem I've been able to fix it after a couple of google searches. But this time I can not find any solution.

```
OS: openSUSE Tumbleweed x86_64 
Host: X550VX 1.0 
Kernel: 5.6.6-1-default 
Uptime: 2 hours, 18 mins 
Packages: 4 (dpkg), 2953 (rpm), 16 (flatp 
Shell: bash 5.0.16 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: Plasma 
WM: KWin 
Theme: Breeze [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: breeze [Plasma], breeze [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: Intel i7-6700HQ (8) @ 3.500GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530 
Memory: 2351MiB / 7848MiB
```

Thanks you very much in advance.

Comment: You can find how I solved my problem here [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/gaszxg/newbie_got_in_problems_could_anyone_please_help/). Basically what happened my cache file was sort of corrupted. Just delete the folder ~/.cache and rebuild it with the command `kbuildsycoca5 --noincremental`. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find how I solved my problem here [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/gaszxg/newbie_got_in_problems_could_anyone_please_help/). Basically what happened my cache file was sort of corrupted. Just delete the folder ~/.cache and rebuild it with the command `kbuildsycoca5 --noincremental`. Thanks anyway!